# How to achieve list slicing in DolphinDB?

Tags: python, sql, slice, dolphindb

In Python, users can access a range of list elements using colons(:).

Suppose there is a vector a of trading days, I want to extract a date from every 20 trading days to generate a new time series. In Python, this can be achieved using a[::20], how about in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, specified data can be accessed using their corresponding indices, which can be scalars, vectors, data pairs, Boolean values, and so on. To achieve your purpose, you can use the `til` function to generate a vector containing the indices of every 20th element, as shown in the following script.

```
t[20*til(t.size()/20)]
```